# SRP: Can the client authenticate using only the stored hash?

Tags: passwords, authentication

Based on the [description of SRP](http://srp.stanford.edu/design.html), it seems that it would be possible for a client application to cache the hashed password `x` and reuse it for subsequent authentifications. The actual password `p` doesn't seem to be used for anything but calculating `x` on the client side.

In addition to the most obvious advantages of SRP over "regular" client- or server-side hashing (no dictionary attacks possible even on weak passwords), are the following assumptions true?

- The server doesn't have to store passwords or password-equivalent data. If the server storage is compromised, an adversary using that information will be unable to impersonate a client after the incident.
- The client also doesn't have to store the password or equivalent data: The hashed password can optionally be stored as an authentication token for use without user interaction; alternatively, it can be discarded and recomputed from the salt `s` and the user-provided password `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are true; they are features of SRP.

In the [description](http://srp.stanford.edu/design.html) you link to, note that the value `x` is computed from the password `p` and salt `s` (so it can be *re*-computed on the client side if needed), and the password verifier `v` is obtained from `x` with a modular exponentiation, which is quite one-way (recovering `x` from `v` requires computing a [discrete logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which is known to be very hard, and not feasible if the modulus is large enough). The server stores `v`, not `x`, and knowledge of `v` is not sufficient to authenticate as a client -- you need `x` for that, which the server does not store and, indeed, never learns at all.